# Download large files from server using SOAP in Android? I m using ksoap2 library. files greater than 30MB throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

```
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_GET_FILE);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GET_FILE, envelope);

        StringBuffer theresponseString = new StringBuffer(androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

    if( !(envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault)) {

        {
            byte[] arrby = Base64.decode((String) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getPropertyAsString("file").toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("Byte", arrby.toString());

            FileOutputStream output;

                output = new FileOutputStream(dir + "/" + requiredFiles.getPath());
                output.write(arrby);

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            status = true;

    }
}
catch (SoapFault fault)
{
    status = false;
    fault.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    status = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code is used to download files when then file size is greater than 30MB it throws OutOfMemoryError at byte[].

Please, guide me to fix the solution.Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: try to set android:largeHeap="true" to your application tag in manifest file.

Comment: Already implemented. Media Size can be 200MB also . Max till now I m getting is 120MB

Answer (score 0):

You can to download the file in chunk size and append it to the same file for every chunk size. Below is the sample code:

```
  @Override
protected Void doInBackground1(RequiredFiles... params) {

    FileOutputStream output;
    requiredFiles = params[0];

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_GET_FILE);
    // adding method property here serially
    request.addProperty("serverKey", serverKey); 
    request.addProperty("hardwareKey", CommonFunctions.getUUID(context).toString()); 
    request.addProperty("fileId", requiredFiles.getId());
    request.addProperty("fileType", requiredFiles.getType());
    request.addProperty("chunkOffset", requiredFiles.getDefaultChuckOFFSet());
    request.addProperty("chuckSize", requiredFiles.getDefaultChuckSize());

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    String URL_GET_FILE = baseURL + UrlApiResource.GET_FILE;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_GET_FILE);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GET_FILE, envelope);

        if( !(envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault)) {

            byte[] arrby = Base64.decode((String) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getPropertyAsString("file"), Base64.DEFAULT);

            try {

                output = new FileOutputStream(dir + "/temp_" + requiredFiles.getPath(), true);
                output.write(arrby);
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }//catch
        }//if

        status = true;
    } catch (SoapFault fault) {
        status = false;
        fault.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        status = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; 
}
```